# Order new posts first in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I am retrieving data from firebase and storing it into list items. But I want to reverse the order, which will bring new posts at the top. What should I add to make it work that way?
[JsFiddle of my code](https://jsfiddle.net/g0eadwkL/)

This is my function for retrieving the data

```
const dbRef = firebase.database().ref();
const usersRef = dbRef.child('users');

readUserData(); 

// READ
function readUserData() {
    const userListUI = document.getElementById("user-list");
    usersRef.on("value", snap => {
        userListUI.innerHTML = ""
        snap.forEach(childSnap => {

            let key = childSnap.key,
                value = childSnap.val()
            let $li = document.createElement("li");
            // edit icon
            let editIconUI = document.createElement("span");
            editIconUI.class = "edit-user";
            editIconUI.innerHTML = " ✎";
            editIconUI.setAttribute("userid", key);
            editIconUI.addEventListener("click", editButtonClicked)
            // delete icon
            let deleteIconUI = document.createElement("span");
            deleteIconUI.class = "delete-user";
            deleteIconUI.innerHTML = " ☓";
            deleteIconUI.setAttribute("userid", key);
            deleteIconUI.addEventListener("click", deleteButtonClicked)     
            $li.innerHTML = value.name;
            $li.append(editIconUI);
            $li.append(deleteIconUI);
            $li.setAttribute("user-key", key);
            $li.addEventListener("click", userClicked)
            userListUI.append($li);
        });
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Firebase offers operations to determine the order in which nodes are returned, there is no operation to return them in descending order.

There are two common workarounds for this:

1. Include an inverted timestamp in the data, and order on that.
2. Reverse the results client-side.

In your case, it is simplest to do the latter: as you can just **pre**pend each message to the list instead of appending it:

```
userListUI.prepend($li);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three methods to sort data with the Realtime database.

- orderByChild() will order results by the value of a specified child key or nested child path.
- orderByKey() will order results by child keys.
- orderByValue() will order results by child values.

Find out more [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sort_data)